# Get Commenter's Profile Picture - Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this code

```
var source = new EventSource("https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/<livestream id>/live_comments?access_token=<access token>&comment_rate=ten_per_second&fields=from{name,id,picture},message,attachment");
    
source.onmessage = function(event) {

}
```

But it only includes the profile photo of **Pages** that comment on the livestream. It doesn't have the profile picture data for **Regular Users** who comment on the stream.

**event** data when a **Page** comments:

```
from: id: "104156481935516" name: "Person 1" picture: {data: {…}}
[[Prototype]]: Object id: "458166779554976_383292267259200" message:
"test comment""
```

**event** data when a **Regular User** comments:

```
id: "458166779554976_751936735966533"
message: "regular user test comment"
```

Is there a way to get the profile picture of the Regular Users? I also can't get their names. I already tried

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<user id>/?fields=picture&type=large&access_token=<access token>
```

but I get the error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '<user id>' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "AfEpta2noSLzSiJ32LdqJAS"
   }
}
```

I only get the error above when trying to fetch other people's profile pic. It works ok when I try to fetch my Page or other Pages.

Comment: Have you got the answer yet? I just had the same problem